# What should/can I do if I flagged a question that needs to be flagged, but chose the wrong description?

Tags: discussion, flags

I flagged a question that had an image displaying <s>full frontal nudity</s> partial frontal nudity with blatantly see-through-clothing. I immediately went to flag for spam as the reason. Then, I realized there was a legitimate question there. So, I edited the question, and removed the link to the image instead.

- Should/can I remove or change the reason for flag?
- Should a flag
  still be inflicted against the question asker when such an easy edit
  was able to be made?

Comment: I've never seen an on topic question that also contains nudity! An edge case indeed. However flags cannot be removed, but will be declined harmlessly (an interesting question is if the original revision history should be destroyed)

Comment: Current feature request to be able to withdraw flags; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags

Comment: @RichardTingle It was a question by a web developer of a "sex finder service" website.

Comment: In the users defence there are countries where such an image would be "safe for work". I have seen huge billboards with topless women on them advertising relatively normal things when on holiday in spain and italy. I must admit I was a little thrown the first time (being from reserved england) (For the avoidance of doubt you did completely the right thing in flagging this)

Comment: Could you please not claim that an image shows "full-frontal nudity" when it does not, in fact, show full-frontal nudity? Or, indeed, any other kind of nudity? A person wearing underwear (even lacy underwear) is, by definition, *not naked*.

Comment: Lacy underwear is one thing. When you can clearly see everything underneath, that's something else. You can try to spin it however you want. The material was absolutely inappropriate.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen is right, full frontal nudity requires no pants (and is extremely not safe for work) whereas I would describe this as bordering on topless

Comment: According to the StackExchance [Content Policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy), "Accounts that use Stack Exchange to post sexually explicit or pornographic material, or links to it, will be suspended."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should/can I remove or change the reason for flag?

No, currently you cannot retract your flag or change its reason.

> Should a flag still be inflicted against the question asker when such an easy edit was able to be made?

Yes, a flag should have been raised because the edited link is still in the post revision history.

You did the right thing by both flagging and editing the post. A better approach would have been to edit the post first and then flag it using the "other" reason and mention about the offensive link of the edited post.

Comment: That raises a new question: How much of a role, then, does the reason for flagging play in the moderation process? Since I flagged it for spam, but it probably should have been flagged for offensive content or other, are the chances decreased that a moderator will take action against the post? Should I ask this as a new question?

Comment: If the existing flag is declined an "other" flag should be used to explain that the problem is in the history

Comment: @crush The flag may have to be declined because otherwise it could become an audit with "known spam"

Comment: @AzizShaikh Yes, I realize now the better approach. I was so shocked by having the NSFW content pop up that I panicked. I'll be better prepared next time. Thanks!

Comment: @crush sure no worries. One declined flag ... dont sweat. Thanks for the help in maintaining site's sanity.