# Change type of flag

Tags: feature-request, flags

I flagged a question recently, and as i realised that i flagged in under the wrong type, my flag was rightfully declined.

Is it possible to change a flagtype once its been flagged, or even cancel it?

Comment: Nope, not possible.

Comment: You may wish to support [this feature request for a way to retract a flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)

Comment: possible duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags