# Why can't you delete your own question? Why is such a restriction?

Tags: discussion, self-delete

I have posted a question Which down-voted and closed. Now I want to delete the question. However I am getting error. **Why is such a restriction?**

Error which I am getting

[image]

Comment: Can you post a link to the question please?

Comment: It's not possible to retract a close flag - see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197208/213634). Besides, in a case where I believe another source is more accurate, I probably wouldn't - if anything, the other answer should be updated to reflect any uncertainties.

Comment: @AndersUP It's possible to retract a close vote, but not a close flag. Also, the linked question mentions nothing about 2 days restrictions. This question should be answered before marking as duplicate.

Comment: As for the "why", this is an anti-vandalism measure. Far too many people would come in here, ask for help, receive it, then delete their question (and its useful answers). We like questions and answers to be useful for future readers as well as the person asking, and deleting answered questions defeats that purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question has multiple answers; this is an indication that perhaps the question is suitable for reopening.

If your question was *not* closed, you'd not be able to delete the question *at all*. Because it is closed but has answers on it, the delay is there to give *someone* the chance to improve the question, perhaps to the point that it can be reopened.

If this doesn't happen in the next two days, you can self-delete it. It'll be auto-deleted after some time anyway, if none of the answers gain upvotes or the question has not been edited for at least 9 days.

See [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) for details on when questions are auto-deleted, or under what criteria open questions cannot be deleted.