# Show exactly how you voted to close, rather than just the first-level category

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

After you vote to close a question, only the top-level vote is visible to you from the post UI.

So let's say I'm on SuperUser and vote to close as *off-topic, belongs elsewhere, belongs on Stack Overflow* (or whatever). If I then navigate back to the question and hover over the "close (*N*)" action link, all it says is that I voted to close as *off-topic*. Clicking on the link brings up the dialog which says the same thing more verbosely.

For example, one might see this and have no way of stepping into that option to see the specific close vote that was cast.

[image]

Sometimes, after a question has been edited, the original close reason that you voted with may or may not apply any longer. But if there is no way to tell exactly how you voted, possibly even after several days, it's hard to know whether retracting the vote to close is appropriate or not. Maybe after the edit the question really doesn't belong on Stack Overflow, because it turned out to not be a programming problem.

**There should be some way to, from the question display, show exactly how you voted to close a question.**

Comment: This feature request also applies to others' votes too: you should be able to see what off-topic close reasons others picked after you voted to close.