# How can I recall or take-back a flag?

Tags: feature-request, support, flags

While reviewing First Posts on Stack Overflow just now, I ran across an answer that gave a solution in code with an explanation in a language not English. Note that the question was in English. I flagged an answer as Very Low Quality only to subsequently realize that the code appears to be a pretty good solution. I realized it probably would have been better to simply edit the post with a translation, keeping the original because machine translations can suck sometimes.

I hate to waste the attention of our illustrious moderators, so I would like to recall or take-back the flag somehow. Is there a way I can do that?

The Help Center has this to say about removing flags:

> **Is there any way to remove flags?**
>
> There is often no need, as offensive and spam flags expire after 48
>   hours if the thresholds aren't reached.
>
> Rolling back a post to a previous state will revert to the number of
>   offensive flags from that particular revision. This allows the OP (or
>   someone else with edit rights) to rollback a post that someone else
>   made offensive in a later revision. However as a general user, once
>   you mark a post as offensive, you cannot take it back.

This, however, only seems to speak to spam flags. Specifically, is there a way I can voluntarily remove **one of my own** flags?

If not, I would like to suggest adding this capability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can't** voluntarily remove your own flag.

Suggestions to add option to remove were already [raised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags) there (on Meta Stack Exchange).