# Don't manipulate existing answers for review audits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audits

I was reviewing Low Quality Post(s) when I've been shown this (then unknown) audit:

[image]

I checked the link, noticed it was clearly spam and duly went to the answer to report it as such (as the review queue only provide the "recommend deletion" option).

The [real answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26646737/91696) looks like this:

[image]

I know, I'm a moron as I should have paid more attention and double check the answer before flagging as spam, but the answer was really there and visually similar and I didn't notice I've been tricked by being shown an answer with a replaced link.

Would it be a problem/hassle to use completely fake answer for audits instead of manipulating existing ones? If someone goes to the source it's not voting blindly, and it would prevent this kind of errors.

Comment: As a side note, this is a situation where the [Cancel misclicked flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500/145401) feature would have helped. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing here was manipulated.

The real answer is really deleted, but you can't see it because you have less than 10k reputation on Stack Overflow. No surprise you were fooled though, since the spam answer just copied other answer that came before it:

> [image]

Comment: Ah, fooled by the 10K tools. Happens to all of us :)