# Allow custom flagging a post after (a still pending) flag as VLQ/NAA

Tags: feature-request, flags, not-an-answer

I have flagged an initial version of a post as Not an answer, which at the site seems okay, since it was more a comment (user uses an outdated browser which isn't supported and doesn't allow adding comments).

Now, the user has edited the post a number of times editing in some stuff that I consider inappropriate. To explain that better than the 'rude/abusive' flag, I wanted to custom flag that post and explain in detail why I think the post is not appropriate and something about the history of that post that was not very obvious (so I really needed to custom flag it).

The flag dialog now says I have already flagged that post, which is true, however my NAA flag shouldn't prevent me from custom flagging it (in my opinion).

I propose custom flagging to be allowed, even if you raised a NAA flag (that one could be automatically invalided, if necessary / possible).

Just to make sure: I have read some related questions on this and those were either bug reports or discussion related to flagging and the flag dialog. This is a feature request to allow custom flagging.

Comment: I agree with this. I flag something as NAA, then go up, do some research, and come back and find out the user is a troll/spammer. But now the only thing I can do is ping mods in chat, which is of course not as good as flagging.

Comment: Even better - since the whole problem is caused by the original flag begin not yet processed... did anyone already considered the option to make the flag over-writable? Begin able to change a pending flag to a more appropriate one could fix many problems, not just this one. Anyway, +1

Comment: That might have a lot of consequences if the item is in the review queue already. Or if you could overwrite your spam flag, it should invalidate the auto-downvote too. @spa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) isn't necessary anymore, since we now have the ability to [retract flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/295232); after retracting your NAA flag you're able to cast a custom flag again.

There's one exception: pending NAA/VLQ flags on locked posts cannot be retracted which leads to [another annoyance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309527/295232).