# Custom flags should be disabled on locked posts when you have another pending flag

Tags: bug, flags, locked

I've flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50061084/4751173) as Not An Answer, and the flag is still pending. Because I want to give [some more background information](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/115763) about this user, I'd like to switch to a custom moderator flag instead. But because the post is locked, I can't retract my flag; the only option left is 'in need of moderator intervention'. Fair enough, but when I try to submit the custom flag, I get the message

> You have already flagged this post for moderator attention

[image]

That's true, NAA flags end up in the ♦ moderator queue as well. But why does the flagging dialog suggest that I [can flag in the first place?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tShYp.png) On a non-locked post with a pending flag, [all options are grayed out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zw97.png) The current behaviour is rather frustrating; all effort in writing the flag text is lost.