# What happens to a flagged post in review if the flag is self-removed?

Tags: support, flags

I recently flagged a borderline link-only answer as NAA.  While the post was in review, the OP edited their answer into shape.  I saw this and self-removed my flag.

Does this invalidate the post from the Low Quality Posts review queue?  Is this the case for all flags and review queues?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The act of retracting a flag itself does nothing but remove the flag from the moderator's queue so it doesn't need to be looked at.

If there is a review item currently open for the post, that's a different story. Posts are pushed into that queue for a couple different reasons, and a not an answer flag on the post is one such reason. **But** the post does have to *maintain* that reason to stay in the queue. If it no longer matches the criteria for having a review item open for it, then the review task will get invalidated at the next cleanup check the system runs.

So, if your not an answer flag was the *only* reason that post was in the review queue, then it will get removed from review within about 15 minutes (via invalidating the review task). If there were other flags or other reasons the task was created, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that (at least for post flagged as NAA in the LQP review queue), the post is invalidated from review.

[image: Review]

[image: Invalidated From Review]

Comment: That review was 'invalidated' because two people voted 'Looks OK' - thus terminating the review in a regular way. I don't think this has anything to do with the flag being retracted, especially since NAA flags are handled by moderators, not by regular reviewers.

Comment: @Glorfindel wouldn't the review be marked as "Completed" in that case, not "Invalidated?"

Comment: @Glorfindel: Normal completions of reviews never say "This item is no longer reviewable". That's only for invalidated reviews.

Answer (score 2):

Retracting flags does **not** remove them from the [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review); a similar question was asked [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333543/4751173), the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags#comment913503_281010) by Shog9 ♦︎ reads as follows:

> flags can set things into motion even before they're acted on, so allowing you to retract flags and re-cast them elsewhere would potentially allow you to circumvent limits in a number of rather disruptive ways.

Note that a 'Not an answer' flag puts the posts in a *moderator* review queue, not (only) in the Low Quality Posts review queue accessible by mere mortals with enough reputation. It might very well that retracting the flag removes it from the moderator queue as well.

Comment: @Kendra OK, that makes sense. I based it on the fact that people regularly ask on Meta why their NAA flags are declined, showing a custom reason for declining which are definetely from mods. Still, I don't expect retracting flags removes posts from review.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I would love to know if removing a flag pulls it from the mod queue as well, that would save mod review time.  If it isn't and the flag was handled by a mod, who would be notified of the helpful or declined flag?