# Was I right to retract my flag?

Tags: discussion, flags

There was [this question on Aviation.SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32506/15982) which I though was unclear about what they were asking (initial revision).

I went to flag to close but accidentally clicked the wrong reason.

After reading the Meta.SE post on [Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/335608) I saw I could retract my flag, which I did.

When I went to re-flag with the intended reason, I wasn't allowed to flag the question as I'd retracted the flag.

The post has now been closed as off topic.

Was I right to retract my flag or would it be helpful to have the flag even with the wrong reason?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In some cases you do want to retract your flag when you have second thoughts. If you accidentally flagged something as spam, you should retract the flag.

If you flagged as unclear when it is actually too broad, I would leave it as is. If a question warrants closure, generally the close reason picked isn't the most important thing. Your flag does set things in motion, so it is better to leave the flag if you believe something has to be done with a post.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @PatrickHofman's great answer, you need to note that even if you raised the flag with the right reason, it could be declined by a moderator if (s)he (personally) doesn't agree with your reason as evidenced in this Meta question on Japanese SE, [Can I ask why my flag was declined?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1612/can-i-ask-why-my-flag-was-declined).

Until I asked that question, I didn't know how flagging works exactly. Now, I know and my advice to you is you don't have to worry about flagging for whatever reason unless you raise the wrong flag as your hobby because

1. Even if it is rare, your right flag could be declined by a moderator.
2. Even if one or two of your flags are declined, no big deal. You will see the warning when you try to raise another flag and all you have to do is paying a little extra attention next time.
3. Flagging doesn't affect your reputation points. The worst case scenario is you are blocked from flagging for a very short period of time. You will learn as time goes by and it won't happen again unless you repeat the same mistake.

Yes, you did the right thing. Even if you hadn't retracted the flag, other users would have taken care of the question.