# What are the odds of SE implementing an old feature request and what can be done to improve those odds?

Tags: discussion, support, meta, old-questions

I am full of great ideas. Well, OK, full of ideas, some of which might be great.  If you squint hard enough. I frequently think up feature requests for SE, because I'm a frequent user.

Sometimes, I decide to stop being lazy and actually come to Meta.SE to post the feature I thought up as a request.

9 times out of 10 (or more often), I discover that someone already thought up the same feature before, and there's an older request for the same thing posted. With no sign of [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) or [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or response from SE team.

Now, there are ways to get extra attention to existing SE (including Meta) posts, but my working assumption here is, that's a fool's work. No amount of effort I can put into an old request will likely make a difference in its chances to be implemented - if SE wanted to do it, they'd have done so already.

**But how accurate is that assumption?**

1. How likely is an old feature request to get completed in general?
2. How likely is an old feature request to get completed after being given extra work/attention by someone else?
3. If the answer to #2 isn't "almost never", what are the most effective approaches to succeed in getting SE team to love an old request a bit more? Bounty? Better examples/business case? Hand-drawn pictures of chocolate covered unicorns?

Comment: "if SE wanted to do it, they'd have done so already" is only true assuming they have infinite resources. They do get around to old, popular requests such as [Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500), which was completed over 5 years after it was made.

Comment: Is this related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange ?

Comment: @rene - in a way, yes. But somewhat tangentially