# Disabled button not visible in flag dialog on some sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, design, retracted-flags

Three days ago, I posted the following [question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3281/70594) on MathOverflow's Meta:

> Since a while, it's possible to [retract a flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/295232) by opening the flag dialog again and clicking the 'Retract flag' button. Of course, if the flag is already handled, retracting isn't possible. In this case, the MathOverflow site design hides the button instead of graying it out.

I thought this issue only occurred on MathOverflow, but today I saw the button looks weird on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) as well:

[image]

This screenshot (from Mathematics Stack Exchange) is how it *should* look like:

[image]

Comment: Maybe [tag:status-bydesign] or something...but if that's the case design should be really reconsidered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug. Thank you for reporting it.

By default, you should be able to see a disabled button (how would you know it's disabled if you can't see anything?). Since you reported this being an issue on at least two network websites, I've gone through all network sites to double-check the disabled state for buttons.

I've fixed the button disabled state for the following network sites:

- Academia
- Arqade
- Christianity
- Database Administrators
- Drupal Answers
- Electrical Engineering
- English Language Learners
- Expression Engine Answers
- Graphic Design
- Math Overflow
- Music
- Puzzling
- Role Playing Games
- Theoretical Computer Science
- Unix & Linux
- Web Applications
- Workplace
- Worldbuilding

This change is now live in production.