# How to remove a flag on a comment? The retract flag button won't work for comments

Tags: support, flags

I am wanting to remove a flag I posted on a comment on EL&U, and can't see how to remove it, there is no 'retract flag button'.  I can't see how to do it in the help centre and would like to know if you can.

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/333472) explains that it is not possible to do so.