# Flagging reversal refusal

Tags: support, flags

For a while now ([since 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)), we've been able to withdraw/reverse flags which were placed in error on questions and answers (there didn't seem to be the same demand for comment flags).

This has been a handy feature when we have that facepalm moment and realise we've made an error, but today (about 20 minutes prior to this post) I tried and was unable to withdraw after having second thoughts on [this question on the electronics stack](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/661117/which-16-v-capacitor-will-work-in-place-of-a-25-v-100uf-capacitor). My attempt was about maybe 3 or 4 minutes after flagging.

My privilege level there is association-bonus only. The flag I raised was rude/abusive/inappropriate for respectful discourse. On attempting to withdraw, the dialogue (at first) came-up with the complete list of options and in red a notice "You have raised a high priority flag", but the "Flag question" button was greyed out, the only other button present was the "cancel" button. The question has since then been closed (and the dialogues changed to reflect narrowed flagging options, but a still greyed-out "flag" button).

**What member or moderator action could prevent flag withdrawal?**

Comment: Reason I wanted to withdraw: I realised I should have edited out the garbage instead.

Comment: You can't retract it if it was already handled (marked helpful or declined) - check your [flag history](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current).

Comment: Disputed, I guess that counts as handled then. Thanks @Glorfindel I should have checked.

Comment: You can also look at the timeline: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/661117/timeline and see if the UTC times (hover over it) of review events match your flag time.

Comment: Thanks @rene The timeline's clear, but the  list of my flags just states the time of flagging as 3 hours ago. If I wait until tomorrow, I think it'll fill in the timestamp then.

Comment: @W.O. aaarghhh. I didn't actually check if the flag history does include the UTC time on hover and it doesn't. So far for UX consistency :(