# Flag declined after a day

Tags: support, stack-overflow, flags, flag-weight

I flagged an answer that was made 8 hours ago from my flagging and was missing half of it.

```
use this code:
```

was the answer

So I flagged it and after 2 hours I saw someone had added code to it:

```
use this code:

<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="small-device.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<link media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px)" href="not-small-device.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

A day later my vote gets declined, thus lowering my flag weight.

Problem is that I didn't flag the edited post, I flagged the first post, which was incomplete. But moderator/admin thought I flagged some later edit I guess.

Comment: Can you post a link to the original question?

Comment: @squillman: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031910/div-with-fixed-width-rendering-too-wide-in-ipad here you go

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96950/can-we-have-a-way-to-undo-a-flag

Comment: I've had this a few times as well. But hey, mods are humans. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105391/why-does-flag-marking-as-helpful-declined-not-always-correlate-with-moderator-act

Comment: @Billy : when I flag something, I don't really wanna have to go back for each flag hoping they haven't updated anything, so I do not have to reevaluate my flags over and over again

Comment: Jaanus: That's why I said "related", not "duplicate" :)

Comment: You may want to comment with a "hey you forgot something or the post got mangled" rather than flagging in these cases.

Comment: Or, if it's a question about HTML (or any other language that uses <>) and it looks like the poster simply omitted the code, you can click the edit button and see if it's actually there but hidden.

Comment: If you were a bit more seasoned, you'd have realized that the poster screwed up his code formatting.  You then would have edited to fix.  **That** would be the proper action to take here.

Comment: @Won't proper action would not be posting pictures of you eating worms

Comment: @Jaanus: Mmmm, worms.  With piss.

Comment: @Won't damn, better drink my own piss

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the [**source of the first revision**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/cc35a820-61af-4245-8b97-d4975e32f423/view-source) in the edit history you'll see that the OP had that code in there, it just wasn't escaped correctly and thus wasn't visible.  So, technically it was a complete answer; there was just a formatting problem.

I'm not able to tell you for sure that this is what caused your flag to be declined, only the mod that declined it can do that.  But it's a thought.

With the "intricacies" of MarkDown, typically if something looks incomplete it's probably just not formatted properly.  I like to make a habit of checking the source of a post to see if this is the case, like it was here.  If you have < 2K rep you can put a suggested edit in there (or a full edit if you have 2K+ rep).  That is all that was done to fix the answer.  The edit added the MarkDown formatting for a code snippet.

Comment: With that said, I still have a question. When I flag something, will the moderator see the flagged post as I flagged it, or as it is at that exact moment?

Comment: That's a good question and one I don't know the answer to (I'm not a mod on any of the sites).  I would post that as a separate question here.