# 'Undelete post' button in moderator flag dashboard on iOS lacks styling

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, ios, flag-dashboard

The new [Moderator flag dashboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330171/295232) works excellent on iOS, thanks to the responsive design. But I couldn't help noticing that the 'Undelete post' button (visible after you've deleted a post) lacks some styling:

[image]

Some other buttons look fine, but @BrianNickel is right, there are more buttons with the same problem:

[image]

I'd expect them to look more like the desktop version:

[image]

Comment: I see it on "Convert to comment..." and others.  Anything that is `<input type="button">` but not a "delete"

Comment: I've pinged our design team to look at this one.  What's triggering this is the fact we're using `<input type="button">` for the button and we're applying a `background-color`.  A background color, combined with the element's UA style rule of `-webkit-appearance: push-button` activates the native style.  Resolve all doesn't get it because `<button>` has `-webkit-appearance: button` which behaves differently.  Delete answer and Helpful... don't get it because they have transparent backgrounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to have been solved at some point in time, the button now has the correct styling:

[image]