# 'Add Another Answer' button lacks styling in Safari on iOS

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, responsive-design, mobile-safari

When viewing the website in full site mode in Safari on iOS, some of the buttons lack the new styling. I've already reported a few instances occurring in the new flag dashboard: ['Undelete post' button in moderator flag dashboard on iOS lacks styling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330510/295232). Here's one visible to all users (with an iPhone or iPad): the 'Add Another Answer' button (left). The 'Post Your Answer' button already has the correct styling (right), as does the 'Add Another Answer' button when viewed in a desktop browser:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed now:

[image]

Comment: @Justin apologies, I mixed up a couple of things. It *is* fixed, that's the most important thing :)

Comment: No worries.. :)