# Can we show when users were last seen on the mod flag dashboard?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard

The mod dashboard currently shows inline when a user joined a stack (see [Moderator Flag Dashboard soft launch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330171/moderator-flag-dashboard-soft-launch) for example screenshots.)

**Could we add a "last seen" string there too?**

Rationale: I visit user profiles fairly regularly for certain types of flags. For answers, on my site, they'll typically get a comment or two suggesting how to improve it. So the "last seen" timestamp helps decide when to take mod action, for instance:

- If they did visit recently, but not since the comment was left, I might leave it be for a little longer in hopes the user will come back soon and edit without a mod having to intervene.
- If they haven't been seen in months, just delete it now since there's no point in waiting longer.

It's also useful for comment flags, like when someone flags a comment as "no longer needed" that I personally feel is a little borderline - I'm more comfortable deleting those if I know OP has likely seen it already.

Currently this takes a couple clicks: the username link goes to "activity" tab, then click on "profile" tab. And if I'm on mobile, I also need to request the desktop site. Adding it directly to the dashboard would make this a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, please. Since we broke the profile into tabs, this has always been my biggest speed bump: "Have they not yet *seen* the <action/notice> or did they just ignore it?"