# Can I withdraw my flag?

Tags: support, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have a way to undo a flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96950/can-we-have-a-way-to-undo-a-flag)

Image this:

I flagged a post.
Then it got edited by the user a few seconds later.
I regret my flag and want to remove it.

Is it possible?