# How to withdraw close votes and flags

Tags: support, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

I have flagged many non-constructive posts and attempted to close them. But later, someone edits the question and makes it full-fledged. At this situation how do I withdraw my close-votes?

Comment: You petition the SE High Commission to withdraw your close vote. It's a long and brutal bureaucratic process and by the end of it, you'd wish you had never wanted to withdraw.

Comment: It will resultant in to disputed or declined by modetaor.

Comment: possible duplicates: [Can we have a way to undo a flag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96950/164012), [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/164012)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. See: [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes).

Since the post is fixed now, it shouldn't keep accumulating close votes. If it does wind up getting closed, you can always flag to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. In such cases it's best to comment that "I revoke my CV/flag blah blah"

It's no biggie anyway--if the question is closed by your vote, you can reopen. That's what closing is for.

If the question is closed by a trigger-happy fellow  on seeing your CV, then still you can reopen.

For flags, its still no biggie. Your flag weight reduced a bit(if the mod didn't see your comment). No big deal.

Comment: "flag weight reduced a bit"  [Not anymore!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119716/164012)

Comment: @dan not really. It's no longer _visible_, but it's still used internally to prioritize the queue

Comment: @Danielδ: It just doesn't get displayed anymore, but it's still there. [Also note that it continues to service one of its primary purposes, which is *ordering the flags in the moderation queue.*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119715/what-happened-to-flag-weight/119716#comment315931_119716)