# Do i still lose flag weight if i got a declined flag, yet the question gets closed?

Tags: discussion, flag-weight

Lets say i flagged a question for moderator attention, the moderator declines my flag. 
The question gets lots of downvotes, gets numerous edits for poor content and ends up getting closed.

Do i still suffer a loss in flag weight because of this?

Comment: You know there is no flag weight any more since a long time, right?

Comment: @juergend: It does exist, it’s just not public.

Comment: @minitech And it does nothing.

Comment: @Doorknob: It affects the number of things you can flag a day.

Comment: @minitech No, that's what the helpful flag count does. I recall one of Jeff's comments saying that if he dropped that row from the database right now, nothing would change. Looking for it...

Comment: @Doorknob: [Also this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119715/what-happened-to-flag-weight#comment315931_119716), and yes, I’m pretty sure the number of declined flags has some influence on queue position.

Comment: @minitech that comment is outdated.  [Flag weight as most people know it is completely and 100% dead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195232/182513).  The new metric looks are ratios of accepted and declined flags, but only recent ones.

Comment: @Doorknob it was [Nick](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188379/please-revisit-the-decision-not-to-let-people-remove-moderator-flags#comment580092_188379), not Jeff.