# Remove a comment up vote

Tags: feature-request, support, comments, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I be able to cancel my up-vote on a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment)

Can I remove a upvote on a comment?

I accidentally clicked it instead of the "Add/View Comments" button.

It annoys me because I actually strongly disagreed with the comment.