# Unlike a comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should I be able to cancel my up-vote on a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment)
>   [Should downvoting be allowed on comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments)

How come it is not possible to cancel a vote fore a comment?

Several times I have voted for a comment by mistake and wished I could cancel it.

Comment: Listen up, removing that notice from your question will get you into trouble. Please leave it intact and do not remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because comments are 2nd class citizens around here.  No rep is at stake so there's nothing to remove.  The only thing votes on comments can do is 1) get you a (single) badge or 2) encourage or discourage behavior in comments.  Because of that it's not a big deal if a couple miscast votes hang around the system.