# Why is 'cancel accidental upvote' inconsistently implemented?

Tags: discussion, support, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I be able to cancel my up-vote on a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment)

**Related:** [Cancelling upvote on comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment)

The above question is closed as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), but I can't find the reason anywhere.

I am not requesting this feature. I simply would like to know what the rationale is behind providing this feature *for answers, but not comments*.

Given that this is implemented for answers, and the general consensus seems to be that the feature would be beneficial to SO, I am left wondering: *why was this declined?*

Comment: That question has **a lot** of viable answers. There is **no need** to post a duplicate.

Comment: Maybe you didn't notice, but the top three (highly upvoted) answers are in complete support of the feature and provide good reason. The other two merely *suggest* it was of low priority, and it didn't seem to me that they were authoritative or in any way related to the [meta-tag:status-declined].

Comment: I am starting to be really annoyed by this website. This question hasn't been answered. The questions and discussions are maybe similar but giving users who are lacking the capability to differentiate questions on small, but important details just shows how flawed this permission system is. the person who closed this should maybe just close his/her browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They just don't think comments rate the amount of support as answers.

It's just not important enough to prioritize.