# Unclear message about un-upvoting comments

Tags: discussion, status-completed, grammar, popups

I think the message speaks for itself...

[image: Cannot undo undo]

> Are you sure you want to undo this upvote? (can not be undone)

Not to mention the "can not". Really?

Comment: Personally, I didn't find it all that unclear. Maybe change it to "This cannot be undone." to make it clear that it refers to the action you're about to confirm.

Comment: @lunboks: I was thinking something more along the lines of "Are you sure you want to undo this upvote? Once you do this, you can't upvote the comment again."

Comment: It's not unclear, but I just don't see why we can't upvote it again if we remove our upvote.

Comment: So what do you propose instead? "can not" should be changed to "Cannot" but apart of that can't see any grammar problem.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: That is the grammar problem. Anyway, the point of this is that "Can not be undone" on a message asking you "If you want to undo" is a little unclear. IMO. *Especially* since you can't reverse it.

Comment: @minitech OK - but what you offer instead then? :)

Comment: @Purmou see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/152859) *We do not want flip flopping, nor do we want people to un-upvote stuff from the past. The only use case is undoing a mis-click*

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: See above? *"@lunboks: I was thinking something more along the lines of..."*

Comment: @Purmou actually no - changed to italics. Few choices in comments..

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: Really? All this trouble for comments? We already have the 5 second limit, so what's the point of restricting the amount of times you can upvote a comment?

Comment: @Purmou I'm only the messenger - but personally agree with what waffles said. The "undo comment upvote" should be used only in case of misclicking - if you misclicked more than that.. well, there is a limit for anything.

Comment: (As an aside, the reason for my edit: if you think your post has any merit for future readers, then please upload images to the Stack Exchange Imgur account, and add plain text for SEO and alternative browsers? Thanks!)

Comment: For the record, "can not" is as grammatically correct and commonplace as "cannot".

Comment: @Bolt: [citation needed], because I've found at least [two](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4620/is-can-not-unambiguous) to [the contrary](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4510/why-is-cannot-spelled-as-one-word).

Comment: Yes, I think the message speaks perfectly well for itself. **What do *you* think is wrong with it?** I have no idea about that. (Sorry, no, I didn't read the extended comment thread to find out. I expected to find this in your question.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alright, I've changed the message to say

> Are you sure you want to undo your upvote on this comment? You will not be able to upvote it again.

Better?

Comment: Yes, much. Thank you. :)

Comment: Much more clear!  ty