# Why doesn't editing my question make it active again?

Tags: support, bump

I tried another method to solve my problem, and edited my question about that an hour ago. It did not bump it and the right sidebar does not say "Active (date)". This is the question:
[How to automatically authenticate LDAP in Windows using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607778/how-to-automatically-authenticate-ldap-in-windows-using-php)

Another question of mine had an answer added to it today, and it was correctly bumped (and the right sidebar says "Active today"). The question:
[SQLite: execute case-sensitive LIKE query on a specific query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590700/sqlite-execute-case-sensitive-like-query-on-a-specific-query)

Why did my first question not get bumped or made active again after I edited it?

To compare another question: [c# against Active Directory over LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469588/c-sharp-against-active-directory-over-ldap)
You can see this was edited 2 hours ago, with no answers from anywhere close to today. This was correctly bumped, as the sidebar says "Active today". My question does not.

Comment: What makes you think it wasn't bumped?

Comment: @Pekka I edited in to explain more. "Active today" is not showing up, as it should.

Comment: Mmm, maybe only edits by other people (or only by mods?) count towards "active". I'm pretty sure it was bumped nevertheless.

Comment: Nice find, maybe "active" in the rightmost column even only applies to something like new answers being posted. You can see the same here: your edit does not add that "active" here either. It surely got bumped though, just like @Pekka expected.

Comment: Hmm okay. That's a bit confusing.

Comment: Hmmm, my edit did not add that "active" either. It surely [bumped it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sBvTp.png) though. One learns something every day ;-)

Comment: Ah, on other posts it links to `?lastactivity`, just like the "xx min ago" on the frontpage. That very "xx min" ago is not clickable when editing the question while no answers have been posted either. (On that front page: try clicking on the "1m ago" as shown [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sBvTp.png); not a link right now.)

Comment: Last "research": `?lastactivity` can also refer to editing a question, like (right now) [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130032/unclear-message-about-un-upvoting-comments/?lastactivity). But apparently it then still needs answers too, for the link to be shown/used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The edit *did* bump the question (i.e. push it to the top of the questions-by-activity list).

The "active" stat in the sidebar is only displayed for questions that have answers.