# What is the "Active X X Ago" link for?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

At the side of *some* questions, there is a sidebar with this in it:

> [image]

That last "today" is actually a hyperlink... To the question I'm looking at.

I'm on this question:

```
meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244457
```

and it links to:

```
meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244457/...?lastactivity
```

Now this is clearly a different link, but to me there is *no difference* between the original question, and after I click the link:

Before vs After (that's a gif image that doesn't change):

> [image]

So what does this link do?

On top of that, the tooltip has a typo:

> [image]

Not sure if the "Z" denotes something important?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thats the last activity of the post. If it was the question itself (question edited, had a bounty started on it, poked by Community, etc), it just reloads the page. If it was an answer (answer edited or posted), this link takes you to the last active answer. Z means that this time is in utc, because all times in SE are in utc.

And, if question was posted and there are no answers, [you won't see this link at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133283/).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! That makes more sense now. Never knew Z was UTC

Comment: @Tim http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones :)

Answer (score 2):

It links to the post with the last activity, which in the case of your example was the question itself. It's a bit more useful in cases where a question [has a lot of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244238/profile-page-makeover-part-3-the-prototype-returns?lastactivity), since it'll take you to the answer in question.

The Z in the tooltip indicates the timestamp is in UTC, since there's no specified timezone offset after it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! That makes more sense now. Never knew Z was UTC.