# Retracting a comment upvote immediately will trigger the 5 second timer

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, comment-voting

If you upvote a comment and then immediately retract that vote, you get this error if you do it too quickly:

> You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds.

Aside from the fact that I'm not submitting a comment vote, but rather retracting it, the [primary and only use case is to undo a misclick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment/129032#129032) immediately after it happened, such that you only have a 60 second window, and not even that if you reload the page.

5 seconds isn't a huge deal, but it makes no sense to put a 5 second timer there if the user is expected to undo it immediately, if at all.

Comment: I hate this and kept meaning to submit a report

Comment: @BenBrocka, I didn't actually mean to upvote your comment, but when I tried to retract it, I got a 5-second-timer note and gave up.

Comment: Same here. Also this question seems to talk about the very same problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164489/cancel-an-upvote-to-a-comment-within-5-seconds-just-fails

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This complaint makes a lot of sense, and the reason this happened was a purely technical implementation detail. This detail has been shown the door now, so from the next build on, this won't happen anymore.