# Cancel an upvote to a comment within 5 seconds just fails

Tags: bug, comment-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting a comment (mine) shouldn’t count as a comment vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote)
>   [Retracting a comment upvote immediately will trigger the 5 second timer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136799/retracting-a-comment-upvote-immediately-will-trigger-the-5-second-timer)

Let's say I upvote a comment, but 2 seconds later I change my mind.

This is the scenario:

1. Click on the comment -> *upvoted*
2. Double-Click on the comment -> `Are you sure you want to undo your upvote on this comment? You will not be able to upvote it again.`
3. Click on Ok -> *the alert disappears*
4. `You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds.` (and the comment vote **is still there**).

I think the comment vote should just be cancelled at this point.

However this happens only when a user tries to do all the above within 5 seconds.

Comment: But "You will not be able to upvote it again." Locking yourself out of a comment vote all in the span of 5 seconds seems a little much.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Yes - seems true. Just tested on your comment and it works like simone said