# Why has the ability to re-upvote been removed?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I be able to cancel my up-vote on a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment)

Why was the ability to upvote/unupvote comments an unlimited number of times removed?

[image]

Comment: The pop-up that you get when you un-upvote a comment does explain this as well.

Answer (score 8):

It was not removed - it was never allowed. Once you un-upvote a comment, you can not upvote it agian.

This was explained when un-upvoting was [first introduced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/167443).

The only reason a comment should be un-upvoted is to undo an accidental click of the upvote arrow. This tends to happen if a user is in a rush to flag a comment and misses by a bit (just a few pixels!).

Comment: I've accidentally click on the UN-vote button before. :-)

Comment: Wow...that no one has called out this ridiculous, unfounded statement in 10 years is unbelievable to me:  "The only reason a comment should be un-upvoted is to undo an accidental click of the upvote arrow."  That is narrow thinking.  How about if I upvoted a comment and then came to a better understanding after re-reading the answer?  That just happened to me.  Because of this inane rule, SO now permanently has garbage data, misleading others that come later to the comment I just inadvertently upvoted and want to, but cannot, fix.  Please don't prevent fixing bad user input.

Comment: @jbobbins if you change your mind, you have 60 seconds to undo the vote, provided you haven't navigated away from the page. If you read the linked answer, you'll see that the limitations on this (at the time brand new) feature were very much intentional.

Comment: @yoozer8 So I have to go re-read a complicated, technical 1000-word answer, think about it, think about what other answers and comments are saying, realize I made a mistake and then get back to the wrongly upvoted comment and undo it, all within 60 seconds?  Coming "to a better understanding" very often doesn't happen within 60 seconds.  Your claim about "The only reason a comment should be un-upvoted is to undo an accidental click..." is simply not true and that thinking leads to bad data in Stack Exchange (speaking from my recent experience). The intentionality is mis-founded and bad for all

Comment: @jbobbins It's a comment vote, not an answer. [Comments are disposable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/167443), and I wouldn't worry too much about  an errant vote.