# How to delete comment if it seems abuse?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

How to delete comment if it seems rude? If someone talks rudely on comments, how to delete that comment?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your case, [as sth says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165124/185080), you probably cannot flag comments because you [don't have 15 reputation yet](https://stackexchange.com/users/2051975/harsh-madhani?tab=accounts).

However, if you did and couldn't see the flag icon, there are two common reasons:

### Your mouse pointer has to be over the comment to see the flag icon.

[image: A comment, with the mouse pointer not over it, is not highlighted.]

---

[image: A comment, with the mouse pointer over it, is highlighted, showing the flag and upvote icons.]

---

[image: A comment, with the mouse pointer over the flag icon, which illuminates and shows a tooltip explaining that this is to "flag this comment as unconstructive, offensive, of spam" (this is also for good but obsolete comments, though)]

---

[image: The dialog that appears when you click the flag icon on a comment.]

*That comment should **not** actually be flagged; this is just an example.*

### For a mobile/tablet device with no mouse, tap the comment.

When there is no mouse and you use a touch-only interface, tap the comment (anywhere) to make the flag and upvote icons appear. Then they can themselves be tapped.

#### And there is a third, less common reason.

### The comment you want to flag has been upvoted, by you.

[image: Comment I upvoted, with no flag icon visible to me.]

After you've upvoted a comment (unless you removed the upvote, which [can only happen right afterwards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/185080)), you cannot flag it.

If for some reason you upvoted a comment that you now realize is rude/offensive, off-topic/unconstructive, too chatty, or (more likely) **has become obsolete**, the workaround is to [flag the post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3118/22949) itself (with a custom flag) and explain the situation.

[image: Flagging a post with a custom mod attention flag explaining that a particular comment should be removed now.]

(If there's more than one comment to flag, one flag on the post is still enough--you can explain it all there.)

Comment: Excellent use of illustrative graphics, despite the disturbing lack of unicorns and [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775).

Comment: Really awesome use of pictures

Answer (score 7):

If you have at least a reputation of 15 on the site, you can flags comments as offensive. If other people or a moderator agree the comment will be deleted.

To flag a comment, there should be a small flag symbol visible to the left of the comment when you hover over the comment with the mouse.

Comment: I cannot see the flag with any comment

Comment: @HarshMadhani: Maybe you need at least 15 reputation to be able to flag comments.

Answer (score 3):

In 2018, two things have changed:

---

1. Comment flags are more visible, you don't need to hover over the comment to show them.

[image]

---

2. [Under some circumstances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313203/295232), you don't need 15 reputation to flag abusive comments anymore. In particular, users can **always** flag comments on their **own** posts (as 'abusive' or 'in need of moderator invention', the other options still require 15 reputation).