# How to flag upvoted comment?

Tags: feature-request, support

I recently asked a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167808/which-pricing-plan-on-imgur). While scrolling , I accidentally  clicked on the upvote button on the comment. The comment is against my question[First comment on question  my given link]. How to remove that?
I have found following from one of the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment) on Meta.

1. You can un-upvote a comment within the first 60 seconds, provided you did not navigate away.
2. Once you un-upvote a comment you can not upvote it again.

But, when I will have upvoted a comment and I want it to be flagged, how should I do that?

Comment: @Manishearth No it doesn't answermy question..

Comment: It tells you that you *can't* flag a comment that you have upvoted, and there is a feature request *already* asking for the ability to do so.

Comment: It does answer it. The answer is "you can't". And it's a [feature-request] just like this one, asking for the same thing (yours doesn't explicitly ask for it)

Answer (score -1):

**No, upvoted comment cannot be flagged**:

Be careful while using touchscreen devices to browse Stack overflow for it sucks upvoting a comment against your own question or comment.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please explain? Is it not allowed to answer my own question here?

Comment: There is no point to answering this question, since it does not bring any new information to light. See the linked duplicate for existing discussion on this topic. Also, this is a feature request, so just saying "No, this can't be done" is no answer.

Comment: @Asions  So why people are saying that my question is answered at that duplicate link?If that is not the real answer...??

Comment: Because your question is answered at the duplicate link. I'm not sure what you mean by it not being the "real answer".

Comment: @Asad The answer is no you can't ..right? So posting the answer here is not allowed?

Comment: Bhushan, the purpose of answering your own question is to share knowledge. This doesn't bring anything new to the table. We all know that an upvoted comment cannot be flagged; in fact, there is an existing feature request pertaining to this. Have a look at the link to see what I mean.

Comment: @Asad Thank you for the information..

Comment: No problem. There are actually a lot of people that agree with your feature request (76 upvotes/ 0 downvotes on the duplicate). Let's hope this gets implemented eventually.