# Cannot "un-upvote" an edited comment

Tags: feature-request, comments

Votes for questions and answers can be *undone* if post has been modified.

Same rule doesn't apply to comments: when I marked a comment as *useful* and this *vote* has been locked then it can't be undone even if comment has been modified after my vote (moreover I may see comment has been changed long time after because thankfully there aren't notifications about them).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I be able to cancel my up-vote on a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment)

Comment: @CRUSADER I don't think it's a duplicate because I know up-votes can be undone. What I mean is I should **always** be able to undo my vote (even when grace time is expired) **if comment has been edited**.

Comment: @CRUSADER on second read it's not duplicate  (I cast a vote then retracted it) - it's asking to do more than what was implemented there.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes.. you are right.. but its definitely related.. Moreover, in the answer by [waffles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/221351) you will notice ***You can un-upvote a comment within the first 60 seconds, provided you did not navigate away. We do not want flip flopping, nor do we want people to un-upvote stuff from the past. The only use case is undoing a mis-click.*** .. So, Unless dev guys chips in for this request :)

Comment: @CRUSADER I agree that most of times it's useless to unvote a comment (unless it was a mistake). But. Problem with comments is they don't have history. You may upvote a comment then you have 60 seconds to change your mind. After two minutes I may edit my comment to say something completely different (and if I ask this it means it did happen) and you aren't able to undo your vote. BTW this may be one of that features that devs won't ever care about...

Comment: @CRUSADER waffles isn't a dev anymore but yes, I agree this feature request is most likely going to get rejected. :/