# How to un-vote comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

How can I un-vote the comment that I voted it earlier? It seems only possible in the first couple of seconds.

[image]

Comment: @AzizShaikh Not work for comments, possible only in the first seconds.

Comment: Judging by your list of questions, may I strongly suggest searching before posting?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Noted with thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Cancelling upvote on comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment?rq=1)

> I just added this, but there are some ground rules:
>
> 1. You can un-upvote a comment within the first 60 seconds, provided you did not navigate away.
> 2. Once you un-upvote a comment you can not upvote it again.

Comment: This is totally untrue. You can simply try on this comment to see for yourself.

Comment: @Cedric what part of it is incorrect? I upvoted your comment, un-upvoted it, and now I cannot upvote it again.

Comment: I had to upvote both your question and your comment