# Why is re-upvoting not allowed for comments?

Tags: support, comments, comment-voting

If I remove my upvote on a comment, then after some time try to re-upvote the same comment, I won't be allowed to. I don't get why we can't re-upvote a comment after we upvote it then revoke our vote. Why is that?

Comment: The reasoning _why_ would appear to be answered here: [Should I be able to cancel my up-vote on a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1170)

Comment: @AlE. Thank you for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the reason is: you can only remove an upvote from a comment if it was an unintentional upvote, and you don't think the comment deserves it.

So if you don't think the comment deserves an upvote, you should not be able to make that mistake again. For your own convenience.

At least that's how I understand [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/225745) by the developer who added it.

Comment: @S.L.Barth any reason for removing last line from my answer?

Comment: I think we were editing your post at the same time. I didn't see it until I went into the edit history just now. Shall I put it back, or would you prefer to do it yourself?

Comment: Please do it :) And thanks for language cleanup. English is not my first language, not even close...

Comment: Done. And you're welcome.

Comment: You answer doesn’t explain, why changing the mind is prohibited. For my own convenience I should be able to upvote and un-upvote as many times as I want.