# You can only undo a comment vote within the first 60 seconds!

Tags: feature-request, comments, error-message, wording

I am not saying that is bad. But it is the only message which shouts a bit (at least I haven't seen others with exclamation mark in the end, all those warnings end with a dot or don't end with anything at all).

> [image]

Please replace the exclamation mark with a dot.

Comment: HEY, YES YOU, EXCLAMATION MARK, ARE YOU SAYING I AM STUPID OR SOMETHING!!! (+1 - A dot would be a bit friendlier)

Comment: There is [another shouting one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/y7ezh.png), which is somewhat experimental; active only on  Prog.SE and Math.SE as far as I know. I think a full stop would be better there, too.

Comment: @Raff I disagree on that one.  It seems entirely intentionally and consistent with the nature of all caps posts.  The issue here however doesn't seems to justify an exclamation point though

Comment: @psubsee2003 FWIW,  the [first version](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6854) of that warning did not have an exclamation point.

Comment: This feature was [added in Australia](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment/129032#129032), where everything is extreme. An exclamation point is therefore customary.

Answer (score 6):

Consistency is important. I think we can agree on that fact that this is an easy fix to make, so let's do it!

(As said before, I don't particularly care if they have other priorities and put this on the to do list for a while, although they could fix it in the same time it takes to write this down...)