# Why shouldn't I revert an upvote on comment after 60 seconds

Tags: discussion, comments, voting

I found that I cannot revert an upvote after 60 seconds of upvoting it.

And I also found [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/298207) which confirms that behavior. **But why is it so?**

[The comment I am talking about is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634133/java-android-plus-minus-button-on-a-calculator#comment51215145_31634133). At first thought, it looks like a very valid comment, but soon you will realize that **there are many edge cases where that would fail**, so I wanted to revert my upvote.

And when I tried to revert I got the dialog asking me to confirm, but before I could read through the dialog and confirm it 60 seconds had passed and I was *not* able to revert my upvote.

***But why go through the pain of implementing such a behavior? This seems to limit people even in genuine scenarios.***

Comment: This is the case with all votes, actually, not just comments.

Comment: @cat Actually, question/answer votes have a five-minute window for changing your vote.