# Remove accidental comment upvote

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Since [cancelling upvotes on comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment) was implemented on the website, I think it should be default on the mobile application too.

I used the mobile app for the first time ever to reply to a comment, and accidentally hit the wrong button.
Now someone I totally disagree with got my upvote (not the end of the world, but would be nice to unvote) and I cannot remove it. I even tried visiting the same site literally 20 seconds later through my PC's web browser, but I was unable to unvote it even there, the button is not pressable.

Comment: I think this is a [tag:bug].

Comment: After experimenting with above comment, there are 2 issues here: 1) I *think* undoing comment upvote is only applicable to PC browser because SE API doesn't have this, and also 2) you can't undo comment upvote after you refresh the page even on PC browser. In conclusion, this is a valid feature request for SE Android app, but the later should be posted as bug report, if you want.