# Unmarking comment as useful?

Tags: support, comments, flags

Somehow, at some point, I marked a comment to [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/56623/54372) as useful. The comment was actually the opposite of useful and I don't want my opinion misrepresented by such an indicator.

I've tried clicking the small arrow () to undo the vote, but it's not a toggle button. The only other option is to flag the comment and it doesn't really deserve moderator attention. Am I missing something obvious? How do I unmark a comment as useful?

Comment: You can only unupvote a comment [under certain criteria.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/266735) I would assume you navigated away or your sixty seconds are up.

Comment: Moderators can't undo your vote too, so flagging is only if you want the comment to be deleted.

Comment: That's right @Kendra, it happened "at some point" which means probably days or even weeks ago.

Comment: On Meta, it's not uncommon for a support request to be duped to the feature request that put in place the feature being asked about, as long as it has the relevant details (which this does).

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I don't mind the question staying closed since I found a relevant answer.

Comment: Indeed, if there is an answer to a question in a different question, I usually close as duplicate.