# How do I get back my upvote for a comment I made though SE Android App?

Tags: support, comments, android-app, comment-voting, change-vote

I made an upvote for a comment that pointed me through the Stack Exchange Android app. Later I thought of getting back my upvote and I tried to do that, but that option (upmark) is not available. Meanwhile I tried to do that other comment that is pointing to some other person I'm able to get back or see that upmark.

Can someone suggest me how to get back my upvote through my handset?
If that option is not available then it could be a bug or request that definitely should be available since the user wants these kind of basic options in the app as well.

*A comment pointed me to:*

[image]

*A comment pointed to others:*

[image]

Comment: comment votes are locked after 60  seconds.

Comment: @rene uuh. Why do we have that restriction? User could get back his comment vote at any time right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have 60 seconds to un-vote on a comment, as stated in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/375663):

> 1.You can un-upvote a comment within the first 60 seconds, provided you did not navigate away.
>
> 2.Once you un-upvote a comment you can not upvote it again

So this is not a bug in the Android app, it's something that all users regardless of platform, are subject to.

Comment: I gone through the link you provided in your answer and still im not able to understand why we have this restriction? Is there any official answer from Mod or SE Employee who implemented this concept?

Comment: @SathiyaKumar "We do not want flip flopping, nor do we want people to un-upvote stuff from the past. The only use case is undoing a mis-click.".

Comment: @SonicWizard Got the point now but in my case its neither flipflopping nor too old(only few minutes back) but still I was restricted to un-upvote. Anyhow now I understood we should be very cautious and have to think twice before upvoting a comment though it's not a big deal ;-)

Comment: @SathiyaKumar Did you navigate away from the question?

Comment: @SonicWizard Yes. I went out of the app few minutes and rechecked my answer as well as comments..

Comment: @SathiyaKumar You can only un-upvote within 60 seconds. Few minutes is too old.

Comment: @SonicWizard Ok. Thanks for clarifying my questions.